# Script or program for indenting automatically Java and HTML files

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, indentation

I'd like to know if you have some idea for indenting automatically some Java and HTML files. The HTML files could contain JavaScript and JSP code.

The ideal program should be executed through the command line on all files in the same time.

Edit : Any other solution?

Thank you,
Bat

Answer (score 3):

[HtmlTidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) should do the trick for HTML files at least.

Here's an example:

```
#$ cat test.html 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html><head><title>Test page
</title></head><body><b>Hello World</b>
</body>
</html>

#$ tidy -i -q test.html 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">

<html>
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">

  <title>Test page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <b>Hello World</b>
</body>
</html>
aioobe@e6510:~/tmp$
```

Add `-m` if you want `tidy` to actually modify the files. (And yes, you can supply multiple files at once :-)

Comment: what about javascript and jsp pages?

Comment: Ah, what a shame. I guess my answer just applies for basic HTML files then. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Use an  IDE like [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). It has a source cleanup option that you could use to set your own custom rule(or use default) for formatting code.

If you are looking for command line invocation, read this [link](http://www.peterfriese.de/formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter/). Copy pasting for reference:

```
<path-to-eclipse>\eclipse.exe -vm <path-to-vm>\java.exe -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter -verbose -config <path-to-config-file>\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs <path-to-your-source-files>\*.java
```

Similarly use for formatting other source like HTML, XML etc

Comment: You are right, Eclipse formatter's are good for every other file types except for JSP's. There are many open bugs as you ca see [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?query_format=advanced;short_desc=formatting;bug_status=UNCONFIRMED;bug_status=NEW;bug_status=ASSIGNED;bug_status=REOPENED;short_desc_type=allwordssubstr;component=jst.jsp;component=wst.html;component=wst.sse;product=WTP%20Source%20Editing;classification=WebTools) I thought it might have been corrected in new releases. I just tried with Indigo, sadly it still isn't perfected.

Answer (score 1):

DrJava( http://drjava.org/ ) has a command line tool for indenting java files if I remember right.

Yes it does http://drjava.org/docs/user/apc.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try checkstyle http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/cmdline.html. I am not sure if it would work for html. However, for java it works like a charm and you can also add customizable rules.

Comment: It's only for Java. I'd like for JSP page

Answer (score 0):

[An IDE.](http://www.eclipse.org/) [And extensions for Javascript](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-javascript-web-developers/heliosr).